# SQL Subquery with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to split one string by the delimiter * into separate columns without including * 
The column y from table x looks like this:

```
column y
*1HS*AB*GXX*123*02*PA45*2013-08-10*
*1R1*B*GX*123*02*PA45*2013-08-10*
*1HS*B*GX*13*01*PA45*2013-08-01*
*1P*C*GXX*123*02*PA45*2013-08-10*
```

STRING_SPLIT is not avalible

The outcome should be this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7
1HS     AB      GXX     123     2       PA45    10-08-2013
1R1     B       GX      123     2       PA45    10-08-2013
1HS     B       GX      13      1       PA45    01-08-2013
1P      C       GXX     123     2       PA45    10-08-2013
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why would you suggest this isn';t a duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) This appears to be an exact duplicate. The OP wants to convert a delimited list into columns.

Answer (score 2):

will you use the below query..

```
select RTRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column y, '[^,]*,', 1, 1), ',')    AS column 1
    ,       RTRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column y, '[^,]*,', 1, 2), ',')    AS column 2
    ,       RTRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column y, '[^,]*,', 1, 3), ',')    AS column 3
    ,       LTRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (column y, ',[^,]*', 1, 3), ',')    AS column 4
    from YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR ` is not a T-SQL function

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `string_split()` does not guarantee that it preserves the ordering of the values.  And, SQL Server does not offer other useful string functions.

So, I recommend using recursive CTEs for this purpose:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from (values ('*1HS*AB*GXX*123*02*PA45*2013-08-10*'), ('1HSB*GX*13*01*PA45*2013-08-01*')) v(str)
     ),
     cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as val, 0 as lev, convert(varchar(max), str) as rest,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id
      from t
      union all
      select left(rest, charindex('*', rest) - 1), lev + 1, stuff(rest, 1, charindex('*', rest) + 1, ''), id
      from cte
      where rest <> '' and lev < 10
     )
select max(case when lev = 1 then val end) as col1,
       max(case when lev = 2 then val end) as col2,
       max(case when lev = 3 then val end) as col3,
       max(case when lev = 4 then val end) as col4,
       max(case when lev = 5 then val end) as col5,
       max(case when lev = 6 then val end) as col6,
       max(case when lev = 7 then val end) as col7
from cte
where lev > 0
group by cte.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=381d72ff9db2f7a03fcd26cc21ff55c2) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can add a table valued function to your database then Jeff Moden's string split function is the best approach I've encountered. It will allow you to maintain order as well.

[Find details here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)